# How to create table where one column contain names of other tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

New to SQL. My data are composed of one master key table, and many other data tables. Note: x y values in different data table has no direct correlations at all.

```
key table as below
key1|key2|dataTableName|
-----------------------
1   |0.1 |     a       |
3   |0.9 |     b       |
0   |0.3 |     c       |
... |... |    ...      |

data table a
X | Y | val
-----------
x1| y1| v1
x2| y2| v2
x3| y3| v3
..|...|...

data table b
X | Y | val
-----------
x1| y1| v1
x2| y2| v2
x3| y3| v3
..|...|...

data table c
X | Y | val
-----------
x1| y1| v1
x2| y2| v2
x3| y3| v3
..|...|...
```

The query will be primarily based on key1, key2 then the X,Y values of the selected tables. 
Data volume wise the key table may contain 200 rows, i.e. 200 data tables. Each data table itself could contain millions of rows. 
The easiest thing to do might have a giant table with all data merged and key1 key2 duplicated for each row od data. But I'm a bit concerned about the efficiency given the data volume above. 
Any advice will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Storing table names in columns does not seem like a good data modeling design.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I'm looking a good way to do data modeling for this. Open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to split the data so that different pieces of data can be accessed efficiently is to use [partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html):

> Partitioning refers to splitting what is logically one large table into smaller physical pieces. Partitioning can provide several benefits:
>
> - Query performance can be improved dramatically in certain situations, particularly when most of the heavily accessed rows of the table are in a single partition or a small number of partitions. The partitioning substitutes for leading columns of indexes, reducing index size and making it more likely that the heavily-used parts of the indexes fit in memory.
> - When queries or updates access a large percentage of a single partition, performance can be improved by taking advantage of sequential scan of that partition instead of using an index and random access reads scattered across the whole table.

Comment: Thank you Roman. I assume you are suggesting to go with one giant table for all data while using partitioning? If I use key1 key2 as a partition, does SQL still physically stores copies of key1,key2 for each row of the data. In my real data I may have 20-30 key columns.

Comment: Key values will be stored in the data table and indices. You may still have your key table that maps `key1, key2, ...` to some unique value that you call `dataTableName`. But instead of it being a table name it should be a value in the column that is used to partition your data table on.